# php - converting objects into array

Tags: php, arrays, object

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM students";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

According to code above the $result is an object which contains the values from database.

suppose there are two names in the database under the column "name" like name1 and name2

now what i want is to convert the object $result into an array which will contain name1 and name2 as array element like

```
$name_array = array('name1' , 'name2')
```

how can i do that ??

Comment: Unless that's a custom DB object, most DB libraries don't return "results" from a query() call. They'll return a result handle/object, which you can then use to actually fetch the results.

Comment: They usually include a means to fetch as associative array though.  As far as duplicate column names go, its up to you to properly alias them when you select.

Comment: `$array = (array) $obj;`

Comment: You need to read a tutorial about php and `(PDO|MYSQL|MYSQLI)`

Comment: Which mysql library are you using?

Comment: $dbarray = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

Answer (score 0):

```html
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // acess the each colum elements using $row["<col name>"]
        //this will loop through all the rows
    }
} else {
    // no rows where fetched
}
```

That is $row = $result->fetch(); will store the values of a row
   in the array $row with key as column names

Comment: is $row from your code is an array ?? like i told above i want an array which will contain the column elements @nithin

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question

got a solution for my problem and realized that it's pretty basic and shouldn't have posted this question. this type of problem should be solved by oneself.

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM students";
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

    $name_array = array();
    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {

        array_push($name_array, $query_row['name']);

    }
```

the array_push function will do the trick.

thank you.